# Show Riemann-Stieltjes integral exists with no discontinuity at the same point

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Say $f$ is piecewise continuous and $g$ is piecewise differentiable on $[a,b]$. $f$ and $g$ is NEVER discontinuous at the same point.

How to prove the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int^b_af \, dg$ exists?

Will this Riemann-Stieltjes integral still be equal to $\int^b_afg' \, dx$?

Comment: If $g$ is the Cantor function, then $\int f\,dg$ will not be $\int fg'\,dx$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ok. Can we derive a general formula for $\int\,f\,dg-\int\,fg'\,dx$? I'm thinking that this difference may make some sense.

Comment: I think probably some things of interest could be said about that quantity, but I don't know about a "general formula".  Google the term "Cantor function" and think about what its graph looks like, and what $\int_0^1 1\,dg(x)$ and $\int_0^1 x\,dg(x)$ should be if $g$ is the Cantor function.